# how to add .html extn end of all page/post url in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

We developed a html static site to WordPress (CMS) blog site ...

For SEO, Static url for best SE cache/crawl...
**Best way to On crawling and indexing sites for the Google index..**

Dynamic URLs vs. static URLs details ref [doordie.co.in/seo/160216](http://www.doordie.co.in/seo/160216)

So, how add `.html` extension end of **all page/post url** in wordpress **without plugins**

For eg. `chennaitechnologies.com/google-adwords/`

To: `chennaitechnologies.com/google-adwords.html`

Any code or `.htaccess` possible?

Comment: I answered you, is just to edit your permalinks options. By the way, this a very old param used by google to index/rank pages. Actually what is relevant is the content of the site/blog, not more the .html at end or meta keys or any other 2000's recipes to rank.

Answer (score 0):

**For posts**

Try the following as perma-link structure:

`%category%/%postname%.html`

**For pages**

There is a free plugin for that called [.html on PAGES plugin](http://www.introsites.co.uk/html-on-pages-plugin.html)

Comment: Its works for post only.. But i need add .html extn end of all page/post url in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing permalinks of your WordPress Blog/site. In wp-admin, look for settings and click in permalinks. Select the custom option and put the .html at the end.

Comment: G.. post url works But page url not working... any code possible without affect any error...